# Entity Framework Include() is not working within complex query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

Consider following LINQ query:

```
var item = (from obj in _db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1)
           select new
           {
                ItemProp1 = obj,
                ItemProp2 = obj.NavProp2.Any(n => n.Active)
           }).SingleOrDefault();
```

This runs as expected, but `item.ItemProp1.NavProp1` is *NULL*.
As it explains [here](http://wildermuth.com/2008/12/28/Caution_when_Eager_Loading_in_the_Entity_Framework) this is because of the query actually changes after using `Include()`. but the question is what is the solution with this situation?

### Edit:

When I change the query like this, every things works fine:

```
var item = (from obj in _db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1)
           select obj).SingleOrDefault();
```

Regarding to [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alexj/archive/2009/06/02/tip-22-how-to-make-include-really-include.aspx) I guess what the problem is... but the solution provided by author not working in my situation (because of using **anonymous type** in final select rather than **entity type**).

Comment: What is the type of `item.ItemProp1` from first query and type of `item` from second query? In my opinion second query should return `SampleEntity` proxy. I agree that the whole problem is because anonymous type that you use in your query. The last thing I would check is `(from obj in _db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1)
           select obj).Select(obj=> new {ItemProp1 = obj, ItemProp2 = obj.NavProp2.Any(n => n.Active)}).SingleOrDefault()`

Answer (score 66, accepted):

As you mentioned, `Include` is only effective when the final result of the query consists of the entities that should include the `Include`-d navigation properties.

So in this case `Include` has effect:

```
var list = _db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1).ToList();
```

The SQL query will contain a `JOIN` and each `SampleEntity` will have its `NavProp1` loaded.

In this case it has *no* effect:

```
var list = _db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1)
            .Select(s => new { s })
            .ToList();
```

The SQL query won't even contain a `JOIN`, EF completely ignores the `Include`.

If in the latter query you want the `SampleEntity`s to contain their `NavProp1`s you can do:

```
var list = _db.SampleEntity
            .Select(s => new { s, s.NavProp1 })
            .ToList();
```

Now Entity Framework has fetched `SampleEntity`s and `NavProp1` entities from the database separately, but it glues them together by a process called *relationship fixup*. As you see, the `Include` is not necessary to make this happen.

However, if `Navprop1` is a collection, you'll notice that...

```
var navprop1 = list.First().s.Navprop1;
```

...will still execute a query to fetch `Navprop1` by lazy loading. Why is that?

While relationship fixup does fill `Navprop1` properties, it doesn't mark them as loaded. This only happens when `Include` loaded the properties. So now we have `SampleEntity` all having their `Navprop1`s, but you can't access them without triggering lazy loading. The only thing you can do to prevent this is

```
_db.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
var navprop1 = list.First().s.Navprop1;
```

(or by preventing lazy loading by disabling proxy creation or by not making `Navprop1` virtual.)

Now you'll get `Navprop1` without a new query.

For reference navigation properties this doesn't apply, lazy loading isn't triggered when it's enabled.

In **Entity Framework core**, things have changed drastically in this area. A query like `_db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1).Select(s => new { s })` will now include `NavProp1` in the end result. EF-core is smarter in looking for "Includable" entities in the end result. Therefore, we won't feel inclined to shape a query like `Select(s => new { s, s.NavProp1 })` in order to populate the navigation property. Be aware though, that *if* we use such a query *without* `Include`, lazy loading will still be triggered when `s.NavProp1` is accessed.

Comment: I'm sad I can't upvote this twice. One of the best answers I've read on SO!

Comment: I realise it's been more than 2 years since you've posted this answer, but in my tests on EF 6.1.3, lazy loading is not triggered if you happened to include `NavProp1` into the anonymous type; relationship fixup does its job there.

Comment: (admittedly what I said only applies when `NavProp1` is a single related entity rather than a collection of related entities - in the latter case, a lazy load still occurs)

Comment: This is actually correct, and has always been at least since EF 4.4.1. In ef-core things are different. I modified the answer to cover these insights.

Comment: Why even bother accessing `list.First().s.Navprop1` at that point instead of just `list.First().Navprop1`? You've already been forced to change the shape of your resulting anonymous object to have a separate `Navprop1` property.

Comment: @xr280xr But that doesn't demonstrate the lazy-loading issue. Normally, when applying this pattern (for example to mimic filtered `Include`) one would do `.Select(s => new { s, s.NavProp1 }).AsEnumerable().Select(x => x.s)` so you get the list of entities. In that case `list.First().Navprop1` would trigger lazy loading, if enabled.

Answer (score 2):

I know this will probably get a few laughs, but don't forget the obvious like i just did. The row in the database didn't actually have a foreign key reference! I should have checked the dam data first before thinking EF Include wasn't working! Grrr. 30 minutes of my life I won't get back.

Comment: i my case, EF had auto-created two columns and the FK was on a column i wasn't using.

Answer (score 1):

If your model is defined properly it should work without any problems.

```
using System.Data.Entity;

var item = _db.SampleEntity
                   .Include(p => p.NavigationProperty)
                   .Select(p => new YourModel{
                         PropertyOne = p.Something,
                         PropertyTwo = p.NavigationProperty.Any(x => x.Active)
                    })
                   .SingleOrDefault(p => p.Something == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

How did you find that `item.ItemProp1.NavProp1` is null. EF uses proxies to load all required properties when you try to access it.

What about

```
var item = (from obj in _db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1)
   select obj).SingleOrDefault();

Assert.IsNotNull(obj.NavProp1);
Assert.IsNotNull(obj.NavProp2);
```

You can also try with

```
var item = (from obj in _db.SampleEntity.Include(s => s.NavProp1)
   select new
   {
        ItemProp1 = obj,
        NavProp1 = obj.NavProp1,
        ItemProp2 = obj.NavProp2.Any(n => n.Active)
   }).SingleOrDefault();

Assert.IsNotNull(item.NavProp1)
```

Of course I assume that you don't have any problems with EF navigation property mappings.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I don't think there is a problem with how EF load values. after using for example methods like  `SingleOrDefault()` all entities and related properties is populated with data... how ever, i update the question hope it helps... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Since this is the first result coming up in web searches, then I want to make sure this answer is also included here. Note that the accepted answer here also worked for me, but this is much easier and seems more correct--at least for simple queries using EF Core:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/71362717/1467396

> Make sure you are using "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore", NOT "System.Data.Entity"