# Why is my data not passed to the view in MVC?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC application and in my Get handler data is passed to the view. However in my view the model is empty.

When debugging and checking over the data, the count of the `IEnumerable<Trip> = 2`. The data is then passed as a parameter in `return View(data);`.

When I iterate through the `IEnumerable` using razors `@foreach` clause I get a

> NullReferenceException

Because the model is empty.

**Screenshot of the action method:**

[image: action method]

**Screenshot of my razor view:**

[image: razor view]

I have done research and I have seen questions here in which the data was not passed as a parameter in the `return View()`. For as far as I can tell all is done well in my case.

Comment: Instead of screen shots, it would be better if you post your code.

Comment: does the repository method return Ienumerable<Trip> type of result ?

Comment: Check for `DateCreated` for null, before you use it.

Comment: Show the sample data along with your repository interface and corresponding class

Comment: Also change the `Name` to check if it's null

Comment: If model is null, the problem may be related http://stackoverflow.com/q/39024354/5426333

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)