# Returning ICollection in Controller Action is missing data

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, angular, asp.net-core

I'm following the Microsoft tutorial on contexts [here](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/data/ef-mvc/intro.html). The problem I'm having is, when i return my student object, which as an ICollection called Enrollments, the ICollection has a count of 3 ( i debugged it and the values are all correct), but when I print out the object to the console the count is only showing 1. Any idea what could be causing the return data to be missing data ? Could it be the way Anuglar2 reads ICollection ?

StudentController.cs

```
public async Task<IActionResult> getDetails([FromBody] int id) {
    var student = await context.Students.Include(s => s.Enrollments)
        .ThenInclude(e => e.Course)
        .AsNoTracking()
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.ID == id);
    if (student == null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
/*
student = 
EnrollmentDate:{9/1/05 12:00:00 AM} [System.DateTime]
Enrollments:Count = 3 [System.Collections.Generic.ICollection<ContosoUniversity.Models.Enrollment> {System.Collections.Generic.HashSet<ContosoUniversity.Models.Enrollment>}]
FirstMidName:"Carson" [string]
ID:1 [int]
LastName:"Alexander" [string]
*/
return Json(student);
```

}

view

```
getDetails(id:number){
    let headers = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json' });
    this.http.post('/api/Student/getDetails', id, {headers:headers}).subscribe(result => {
        console.log(result.json()); 
    });
}
```

Console

```
Object { id: 1, lastName: "Alexander", firstMidName: "Carson", enrollmentDate: "2005-09-01T00:00:00", enrollments: Array[1] }
```

SchoolContext.cs

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public SchoolContext(DbContextOptions<SchoolContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<Course> Courses { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Enrollment> Enrollments { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Student> Students { get; set; }
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Course>().ToTable("Course");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Enrollment>().ToTable("Enrollment");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>().ToTable("Student");
    }
}
```

Soultion 
Startup.cs

```
    // Add framework services
    services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
        options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
    });
```

Comment: On your linq query, you're calling SingleOrDefault. That will return a single object or the first it can find, if you have objects with the same ID.

Comment: Oh I see what you mean. A property of the object is an array. It might be the way you chain the linq query. Try SingleOrDefaultAsync before ThenInclude. See if that works

Comment: @Brian if i switch the two it says 'Task<Student>' does not contain a definition for 'ThenInclude' and no extension method 'ThenInclude' accepting a first argument of type 'Task<Student>' could be found.

Comment: @John I understood what you wanted, I need to check this in project.

Comment: My bad, I meant Include, not ThenInclude.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ASP.NET Core API only returning first result of list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024354/asp-net-core-api-only-returning-first-result-of-list)

Comment: @John perhaps, it's the format of the outcome? Expand the array of your console log, check if it's a type instead of the actual data you wanted. If it is atype, you might want to parse the student object into JSON on your controller before returning it.

Comment: @ademcaglin Ill give it a try. What isthe namespace i have to include? The name 'ReferenceLoopHandling' does not exist in the current context.