# Linq to SQL WHERE clause causes ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have the following method in my Web Api controller:

**TemplatesController.cs**

```
// GET: api/Templates
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTemplate()
{
    ApplicationUser currentUser = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(HttpContext.User);
    IQueryable<Template> templates = from template in _context.Template
        where template.User.Id == currentUser.Id
        select template;

    return Ok(templates);
}
```

Which causes Chrome to throw an error `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING`.

When I take out the WHERE clause, however, it works fine:

```
// GET: api/Templates
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetTemplate()
{
    IQueryable<Template> templates = from template in _context.Template
        select template;

    return Ok(templates);
}
```

The `ERR_INCOMPLETE_CHUNKED_ENCODING` does not occur in Firefox or Edge, but the data fetch still fails silently.

Comment: Did you try to call .ToList()?

Comment: I agree with @HungCao.  When you use `Where` and `OrderBy` and certain other methods, you no longer have a `List<T>` so certain things fail later down the road.  I would try `return Ok(templates.ToList());`

Comment: I've tried `return Ok(templates.toList());` now, but that hasn't changed anything.

Comment: Can you open F12 window in Chrome and see what did your api response?

Comment: Try to disable the antivirus if you have any.

Comment: Please refer [this link](http://thisinterestsme.com/err_incomplete_chunked_encoding/) it should solve your problem.

Comment: The error seems to have magically disappeaed... I went to sleep, turned my machine back on and am no longer able to reproduce. Still not getting the data, but the actual error is gone.

Comment: For the sake of completeness, [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024354/asp-net-core-api-only-returning-first-result-of-list) ended up fixing the data not being fetched. Still don't know how the error disappeared though.