# Why does ASP.Net Core Web API return a partial resut for my object?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get my full object to be returned from my Core ASP.Net WebAPI method.

I've been thinking this whole time I was not selecting my object correctly with my includes or there was something wrong with our patterns.
But now I notice if I place my breakpoint right before returning the object, the complete object is there from my query and ready for me to return.

So this is the method:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<Case> AddCase([FromBody] EmployeeCaseFromBodyModel model)
    {
        Case employeeCase = new Case()
        {
            PrimaryEmployeeId = model.EmployeeId,
            LerSpecialistId = model.LerSpecialistId,
            InitialContactId = model.InitialContactId,
            InitialConsultDate = model.InitialConsultDate,
            Notes = model.Notes
        };

        Case newCase = await _caseGenericService.InsertAsync(employeeCase);

        newCase.EmployeeCases = new List<EmployeeCase>();
        newCase.EmployeeCases.Add(new EmployeeCase
            {
                CaseId = newCase.Id,
                EmployeeId = model.EmployeeId
            }
        );
        await _caseGenericService.UpdateAsync(newCase);

        newCase = await _caseGenericService.GetSingleIncludingAsync(newCase.Id,
            new Expression<Func<Case, object>>[] {
            a => a.InitialContact,
            b => b.LerSpecialist
        });

        return newCase;
    }
```

If I place my breakpoint at this line:

```
return newCase;
```

The object looks like this:

[image]

So see my object is populated even with deep properties.

But the API Post returns this JSON result:

```
{
  "initialContactId": 2,
  "initialContact": {
    "email": "test@hrsa.gov",
    "organizationId": 1,
    "supervisor": "Beth Dillon",
    "supervisorEmail": "supervisor@hrsa.gov",
    "firstName": "Cindy",
    "lastName": "Adams",
    "notes": "Notes 2",
    "bargainingUnitId": 1,
    "payPlanId": 8,
    "gradeRankId": 5,
    "positionTitleId": 25,
    "seriesId": 2,
    "isUnionEmployee": true,
    "organization": null,
    "bargainingUnit": null,
    "payPlan": null,
    "gradeRank": null,
    "positionTitle": null,
    "series": null,
    "unionHours": null,
    "unionEmployeeYesNo": "Yes",
    "employeeCases": [
      {
        "employeeId": 2
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

It only returns the InitialContactID and the IntitialContact with all of the properties filled for intialContact.
But no LerSpecialist and no top level simple properties like Id and IntitialConsultDate?

Why does it behave like this?

Shouldn't it return the exact complete object I tell it too?

I also tried making the return type a Task of IActionResult instead of Task Case and returning an ObjectResult instead of a Case.
But no go.

Answer (score 2):

Found it here:
[ASP.NET Core API only returning first result of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024354/asp-net-core-api-only-returning-first-result-of-list)

This line did in StartUp.cs for me:

```
services.AddMvc().AddJsonOptions(options => {
            options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            });
```