# Select multiple tables using asp .net core and Oracle 8i database

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, devart, oracle8i

I am pretty much trying to do a query for multiple tables from an Oracle 8i database. Using Devart dotconnect to a .net core applicaiton. I am aware the joins were not available back then, but has anyone found a way to do this?

I have tried the solution in this link: [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024354/asp-net-core-api-only-returning-first-result-of-list) but just like the question i still retrieve null for the second table. My models are exactly the same

I have also tried the 'FromSql' and passing an sql. I am able to run this query in Toad for Oracle and retrieve data from multiple tables, but it does not work in my application.

```
var listData = _context.Team
      .FromSql("select * from Team where order = '178'")
      .ToListAsync();
```

This also returns a json for the firsts table and null for the second table values.

Can this not be achieved with oracle 8i or the problem else where or is there a workaround.

Comment: need alittle more to go on, like class structure, select only shows 1 table...

Comment: @mvermef the example in the link is just like my class structure, that is what i used to create the class structure. the FromSql has 3 tables, the snippet i had is to show how i implement that

Comment: keep in mind that your SELECT is only 1 table.  Secondly EF Core **doesn't** _implement lazy loading yet_, at least not in 1.1 and I don't think it will in 2.0's initial release either.

Comment: as far as I can tell they aren't supporting EFC either... .net standard 1.3 is all that is available which means full .net stack with OracleCommands...
https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/docs/NET-Standard-Compatibility.html  on top of that https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/oracle/compatibility.html  8i isn't supported for EF without oracle9+ ( 9.2.0.4)

Comment: not trying to be Debbie downer here but I think you are stuck with versioning issues at this point, Oracle doesn't even support .NET Core, at least not yet.