# Error Adding Controller because of Model Relationships

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core, db-first

I get an error message when trying to add a controller (presumably) because of incorrectly defined relationships. I cannot find what my issue is.

I have two simple models: Scenario and Condition. A Scenario can consist of multiple Conditions, but a Condition will only be associated with a single Scenario. (My DbContext is MySQL, not SQL Server).

Error: There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The relationship from 'Condition' to Scenario.Conditions with foreign key properties {'ScenarioId: int'} cannot target the primary key {'Id': int} because it is not compatible. Configure a principal key or a set of compatible foreign key properties for this relationship.'

(I had no problem creating the ScenariosController, and returning data from the API. Where I expected the array of Conditions to be, there were only null values. Also, the error occurred while trying to add the ConditionsController.)

```
public class Scenario
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }

        public ICollection<Condition> Conditions { get; set; }
    }

public class Condition
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ScenarioId { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Preference { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("ScenarioId")]
        public Scenario Scenario { get; set; }
    }


public class EvaluatorContext : DbContext
    {
        public EvaluatorContext(DbContextOptions<EvaluatorContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<Condition>()
                .HasOne(s => s.Scenario)
                .WithMany()
                .HasPrincipalKey(s => s.Id);

            modelBuilder.Entity<Scenario>()
                .HasMany(s => s.Conditions)
                .WithOne()
                .HasForeignKey(c => c.ScenarioId);
        }

        public DbSet<Scenario> Scenario { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Condition> Condition { get; set; }
    }
```

I want to be able to add a ConditionsController using the Code Generator without encountering an error message and to be able to return a Scenario object with the list of associated Conditions, and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue with not being able to add a controller with the code generator was due to some issue with how I was defining relationships with Fluent API in the OnModelCreatingMethod(). I got rid of those and the error went away. As it turns out, they are not mandatory in order to make a controller actually run.

I also had another issue... the .Includes() statement did not work to actually load related entities. The answer for that issue, at least in may case, is here:

[ASP.NET Core API only returning first result of list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39024354/asp-net-core-api-only-returning-first-result-of-list)