# C# EF API Controller Not Loading Many to Many Array

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first, json.net, asp.net-apicontroller

I have the following two classes in a C# ASP.Net application Entity Framework code-first setup

Facility Class;

```
public class Facility
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name {get; set; }
    public ICollection<SubscriberList> SubscriberLists {get; set;}
}
```

SubscriberList Class;

```
Public class SubscriberList
{
    public SubscriberList()
    {
        Facilities = new HashSet<Facility>(); //not sure if I need this.
    }
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Facility> Facilities { get; set; }
}
```

With the following Configuration;

```
public class SubscriberListConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<SubscriberList>
{
    public SubscriberListConfiguration()
    {
        HasMany(w => w.Facilities)
            .WithMany(s => s.SubscriberLists)
            .Map(m =>
            {
                m.ToTable("SubscriberListFacilities");
                m.MapLeftKey("SubscriberListId");
                m.MapRightKey("FacilityId");
            });
    }
}
```

Now I have the following ApiController

```
public List<SubscriberList> GetSubscriberLists()
{
    var list = _context.SubscriberLists
        .Include(c => c.Facilities)
        .ToList();
    return list;
 }
```

When calling the Get request to the /api/SubscriberLists I get the following Json which is missing the "facility name"

```
[
    {
        "Id": 2,
        "ClientId": 1000001,
        "Facilities": [
            {
                "$id": "1"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "Id": 3,
        "ClientId": 1000002,
        "Facilities": [
            {
                "$id": "2"
            },
            {
                "$id": "3"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

As you can see it does not return the `Facility.Name`, only the `Facility.Id`.
I tried by adding the virtual keyword before the ICollection.
Tried changing `ICollection<>` to `IList<>` as well to `List<>`
Also tried adding the attribute `[JsonProperty("Facilities")]` on top of the `Facilities` field.
Also tried to iterate the returned list querying the facilities to trigger the loading. Nothing helped so far.

The interesting thing is that in debug mode, I can see everything loaded as expected, I see all the `Facility.Name` fields populated. I'm afraid the issue here lies at the Json Serializer, but have no clue how to troubleshoot this.

What's my next step?

Thanks in advance

**Edit;**

Worth to add. When navigating to the Api url in the browser which results in getting XML data instead of Json, I get the following result in the `Facilities` array.

```
<Facilities>
    <Facility xmlns:z="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" z:Id="i1"/>
</Facilities>
```

Comment: Are you sure that the facility with id 4 has Name different then 'null' in your DB?

Comment: @VadimMartynov Yes, the Facility Id 4 (now 2) has a name, but this is even more strange, that the $id numbers it returns is not actually from the database, it just increments for each instance in the returned data. (I omitted a few of the responses for simplicity. I now updated it to 1,2 and 3)

Comment: This sounds like result of JSON serializer [`ReferenceLoopHandling`](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/SerializationSettings.htm) set to `Ignore`. Do you have any issues deserializing that JSON?

Comment: @VadimMartynov actually come to realize that the "$id" does not represent the actuall Id field returned from the database. It's just a "Json.PreserveReferencesHandling" placeholder. Which begs the question, why is only this returned instead of the actual data.

Comment: @IvanStoev I've added the following line in the WebApiConfig.cs file but still have the issue. `config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Serialize;`
Is this what you've recommended, or else please explain.

Comment: Added the XML serialization version in the question.

Answer (score 1):

I think your mapping is a little off, maybe try this

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Facility>()
.HasMany<SubscriberList>(s => s.Facilities)
.WithMany(c => c.SubscriberLists )
.Map(cs =>
 {
   cs.MapLeftKey("FacilityId");
   cs.MapRightKey("SubscriberListId");
   cs.ToTable("SubscriberListFacilities");
});
```

[Configure Many-to-Many relationship](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/configure-many-to-many-relationship-in-code-first.aspx)

Comment: I'm not really sure what you've added in you answer. The only thing I see is that you've started the configuration with the Facility while I started the configuration with the SubscribeList. (In many to many relationship there is no difference on which class you do the configuration)
I've updated the question to include the whole configuration class so you get the whole picture.
Let me know if you still see that I missed anything from your answer.
Thanks.

Comment: More. I don't think the issue here is in my mapping. The database looks exactly as expected, and I've got the correct results with regular MVC controler, and I see the correct data in debug mode when inspecting locals. The only issue here is when it comes to get the data via the "API" controller.

Comment: I see, there might be a problem with include in your case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055327/entity-framework-include-is-not-working-within-complex-query.

Comment: Also, to see actual queries generated by EF, you can turn on log https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mpeder/2014/06/16/how-to-see-the-actual-sql-query-generated-by-entity-framework/

Comment: Would you elaborate on what's wrong with my Include statement, I see no issue with it.

Comment: Include is not a guarantee.  I may be wrong, but seems what you are doing is eager loading relationships, and EF is dropping your include. Reason why I am saying that you do eager loading, is because you didn’t mark your child collections as virtual.  You can look at lazy loading vs eager loading, both have its own cons and pros and depending on your project’s needs.

Comment: Several solutions that may help you
Solution 1: 
var dbResult = _context.SubscriberLists;
var list= dbResult.Include(c => c.Facilities).ToList();
return list

Comment: Solution 2: var list= _context.SubscriberLists.Select(s => new { s, s. Facilities }).ToList(); 
Entity Framework has fetched SubscriberLists and Facilities entities from the database separately, but it glues them together by a process called relationship fixup. As you see, the Include is not necessary to make this happen. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28055327/entity-framework-include-is-not-working-within-complex-query

Comment: Solutions 3: you can enable lazy loading for entire DB in configuration, or you can turn on lazy loading for a particular property by making it virtual.